# Is seedy the right word?

Tags: word-usage

I use the word “Seedy” quite often in my daily speech, mostly to describe how sick or poorly someone is feeling (I.E. “I’m feeling quite seedy today.” “Are you feeling seedy?”) or describing something of poor quality or standard (I.E. a seedy Wi-Fi connection or seedy driving skills). However, I am unsure if I am using the right word. The only examples I could find were things that described places (seedy bar, seedy motel) and attire (seedy clothes). I also use it when describing something dodgy or shady (a seedy website).

Comment: It's nonstandard, but sort of cute.  You'd have to make sure the person really understood what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

You won't hear seedy used that way in American English. Seedy implies dirty and possibly immoral, such as a seedy bar. Ill, sick and under the weather can be used instead (at least in American English).

Comment: That is more or less how it is used in Britain, and probably the only context in which I would use it - which I think is what @Janus Bahs Jacquet is getting at. A stronger, and slightly obscene word, which has taken hold in Britain, and which could certainly be used for anything from a wi-fi connection to a bad driver is *poxy*.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be answered by simply [looking it up in a dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seedy).

> - Sordid and disreputable.
>     *‘his seedy affair with a soft-porn starlet’*
> - Shabby and squalid.
>     *‘an increasingly seedy and dilapidated property’*
> - (dated) Unwell.
>     *‘she felt weak and seedy’*

Though dated when referring to feeling ill, all usages you've listed are correct and contained within the dictionary definition of the word.

Comment: Using it to mean ‘unwell’ is quite dated, though. I’ve never known anyone who’d dream of actually using it in normal speech. And the meaning ‘substandard, of poor quality’ can’t really be subsumed under any of those three main meanings of _seedy_. I would definitely not use it to describe Wi-Fi connections or driving skills. Actually, I might use it to describe driving skills, but it wouldn’t just mean a bad driver then—it would be someone who drives like a James Bond mafia villain, minus the actual skill as a driver. Not just bad driving, but _morally_ bad driving.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: That's more an argument about allowing looser definitions and considering such usage to be correct or not. "Shabby" seems adequately encapsulating for the definition of "substandard, of poor quality" and by extension this should also apply to a bad Wi-Fi connection (for which "poor quality" is actually used frequently). As to driving skills, while not commonly used, it can be encapsulated by "sordid", which is defined as "involving **immoral or dishonourable actions** and motives; **arousing contempt and moral distaste**", at least if we're talking about **reckless** driving

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'm not saying these definitions are common or even widely understood. But if you understand the dictionary definition of "seedy", the OP's usages are sufficiently understandable, in my opinion, and none of them have definitions that truly clash or contradict valid usage.

Comment: _Shabby_ itself has several meanings; the example chosen and the fact that it says not just “shabby” but “shabby and squalid” strongly indicates that the sense of _shabby_ intended here is the most literal one, referring to dilapidatedness or worn-outness from overuse or lack of care. A bad Wi-Fi connection could easily be described as shabby (meaning just ‘bad’ here), but that doesn’t mean any other word whose definition is given as “shabby” can be substituted. A Wi-Fi connection can’t be dingy, ramshackle, scruffy, tacky, or insalubrious, for instance.

Comment: 'This question can be answered by simply looking it up in a dictionary.' should accompany a close-vote, not an answer.