# Guided rockets Vs Missiles

Tags: science, military

In the context of military weapon and ammunition, missiles are said to be guided but rockets are not. yet the latest trends of rocket says, there are rockets with guidance system, though they are called rockets. There must be some features that distinguish these guided rockets from the missiles, ie the magnitude of guidance system, structure, maneuverability etc. What are those features that separate the guided ROCKETS from being missiles?

Comment: Technically, a *rocket* is something propelled using a fuel and oxidizer, while a *missile* is propelled by inertia.  IOW, it's a rocket until the fuel runs out, then a missile.

Comment: @HotLicks Correct, and the final stage may be guided, yet have no rocket engine at all.

Comment: Like rockets, missiles can be either guided or unguided. This question doesn't appear to be about EL&U at all.

Comment: A missile is anything you throw/hurtle at your oppenent. A rocket is a specific kind of missile that uses rocketry to propel itself. An Arrow fired from a bow is a missile, but not a rocket. A _kamikaze_-plane was certainly a guided missile, but not a rocket.

Comment: You're wrongly assuming that words are always used logically and precisely.

Comment: Hey, it's not missile science...it's English.

Comment: All of the above comments arguing what missiles/rockets are, seem to be very loose in regards to the definition of a missile/rocket as a **weapon** or as a generic English word. [There is a difference between a (projectile) missile and a (weapon) missile](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/missile), and [a similar distinction exists for rockets](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rocket). I suggest that we focus on the weapon-related terms, as OP is clearly asking about the weaponry and not the words in general.

Comment: @Flater In that case, we're probably outside normal English usage and into military jargon/s, and the question is better asked on a dedicated website. One arms manufacturer's 'rocket' may well be another's 'missile'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I was referring to the distinctions made _in the dictionary definitions themselves_ (e.g. HotLicks' assertion that missiles are propelled by inertia, which is true for the "projectile" but not the "weapon" definition, cfr the link I supplied) . You're confusing my answer with my comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited to https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102381/weapons

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of overlap between "rocket" and "missile".

[Missile Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile)

> In modern language, a missile is a self-propelled precision-guided munition system, as opposed to **an unguided self-propelled munition, referred to as a rocket (although these too can also be guided)**.
>
> In military usage, munitions projected towards a target are **broadly** **categorised** as follows:
>
> - A powered, **guided** munition that travels through the air or space known as a **missile** (or guided missile).
> - A powered, **unguided** munition is known as a **rocket**.
> - Unpowered munitions not fired from a gun are called bombs whether guided or not; unpowered, guided munitions are known as guided bombs or smart bombs.

Notice the "broadly categorised". There is a lot of overlap between these terms.

---

However, the [rocket Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_(weapon)) might have disambiguated it better:

> In military parlance, a rocket differs from a missile primarily by lacking an active guidance system; early missiles were known as "guided rockets" or "guided missiles". **Some rockets were developed as unguided systems and later upgraded to guided versions, like the GMLRS, and these generally retain the term "rocket" instead of becoming missiles.**

In other words, the "rocket" designation can be kept if the specific weapon was **initially designed** as a rocket.

---

### Footnote:

Notice that the referenced definitions refer to **military** jargon/parlance/usage. The English dictionary defines these more broadly:

> [**Missile**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/missile)
>
> - An object which is forcibly propelled at a target, either by hand or from a mechanical weapon.
> - A weapon that is self-propelled or directed by remote control, carrying conventional or nuclear explosive.
>
> [**Rocket**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rocket)
>
> - An elongated rocket-propelled missile or spacecraft.
> - A cylindrical projectile that can be propelled to a great height or distance by the combustion of its contents, used typically as a firework or signal.

Going by the English definitions, I would say that *most* missiles are rockets, and vice versa.

These definitions clash with the established military jargon; and in this case I'm inclined to defer to the military definitions, as they seem to make more of a meaningful distinction. The dictionary definitions are broad and are not really trying to make a distinction between the two.

Comment: In what way is doing OP's reasonable research beneficial to the site?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: **Damned if you do** (_"In what way is doing OP's reasonable research beneficial to the site?"_), **damned if you don't** (_Straight from the horse's mouth: ["looking up 'alphabet' in a reasonable dictionary is something I consider mandatory on a site aimed at linguists"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408542/is-there-a-collective-word-for-the-different-alphabets-used-by-different-langu#comment972902_408542)_)

Comment: This question lacks any reasonable research. Why do you thing other people giving responses avoided 'answers'? Cutting and pasting from the obvious Wikipedia articles is hardly the same as providing hard-to-find quotes from Svartvik and Quirk.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Did you not read the footnote? I supplied the dictionary references too, and explicitly explained that these definitions are much broader (too broad to make a meaningful distinction between the two). As much as we like referring to the dictionary, it does not contain all field-specific jargon, and such jargon can be relevant for a given topic (as is the case here).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Furthermore, as per your own words: ["Dictionaries are often slow to adopt new scholarship."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404639/is-japanese-in-the-japanese-people-from-japan-collectively-a-noun-or-an-ad#comment962743_404639). It stands to reason that dictionaries are equally slow at adopting designations for military technology.

Comment: It's unrealistic to expect a general dictionary to cover all jargons, especially when there isn't consensus among the experts using them. So I'm certain this is wrongly scoped for ELU. It would doubtless be POB on a military terminology site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: You keep flipflopping. First, you accused me of _"doing OP's reasonable research"_, but the next comment then stated that _"this question lacks any reasonable research"_. Your stance on the necessity of dictionary definitions in an answer has varied (cfr links), [and you've also indirectly stated that an answer should consist of more than a dictionary definition.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407101/is-seedy-the-right-word/407103#comment969760_407103) So if I understand you correctly, I'm not allowed to reference the research that is needed for a good answer?

Comment: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102381/weapons

Comment: A question that lacks obvious research should be close-voted, which I did. An answer that does the obvious research OP should have shown undermines the credibility of the site. Someone presenting such LMGTFY research may elsewhere have been addressed for not supplying references in an answer to a **valid** question. // If OP added reasonable research here, that would remove the 'lack of research' CV-reason. But a fuller answer would delve into (doubtless conflicting) military jargons. Davo's suggested forum seems far more appropriate.